# Proof by contradiction and division by $0$

Tags: proof-writing, paradoxes

Proof by contradiction is based on the fact that if, as a consequence of a statement's truth, we reach a contradiction, then that statement must be false, since contradictions do not exist in mathematics.

So proof by contradiction assumes that there are no contradictions in mathematics. But a simple contradiction can be easily demonstrated by the fact that for some integer $x$, $\frac 10$ can either equal $\pm\infty$ as can be observed by plotting a graph for $\frac 1x$: at $x = 0$, the curve stretches to both infinities. This contradicts the fact that something cannot have two values at once, a core postulate of mathematics.

Is there a fallacy in my argument?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Mathematics is a very old subject, and a lot of very smart people have worked at it over the centuries; if you find what seems to you to be a contradiction, especially at so elementary a level as this, you should **very** strongly suspect that you’ve misunderstood something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your argument is based on a false assumption: far from having two values, $\frac10$ is undefined and therefore has no value. The statements $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac1x=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}\frac1x=-\infty$ are abbreviations for precise descriptions of how the function $f(x)=\frac1x$ behaves near (but not at) $x=0$; they say nothing about the undefined symbol $\frac10$.

Answer (score 3):

I think the division of a nonzero number by $0$ is meaningless because if for example $a\neq 0$ and $a/0=b$ be a number so $0=0\times b=a$ and so we face to a simple contradiction. That's why we know $1/0$ as a meaningless thing. However $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}(1/x)=+\infty$$ shouldn't be mixed with that meaningless one.

Comment: I like this answer! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks :). But there is considerable distance till I can tell what I am thinking about a maths problem here appropriately. This can be easily found out by comparing my answers with another answers. Sometimes, mine are soooo elementary and this makes me ashamed to be among others. :)